# The observer call method returns null

Tags: android, retrofit, observable

I am working in Restful android using square's retrofit REST Client Library. The problem that I have faced is when using Observable of retrofit it returns **null** in the Observer's call method. But when i call the API with callback it returns the data. The interface that i used is as follows:

```
@GET("/Contact/{Id}")
public Observable<Contact>(@Query("Id")String Id);
```

And in the main Activity i called this observable's object like this

```
APICall.GetSingleContact("5bc10c61-9dc8-4580-864f-e4b0bc05749a")
    .subscribe(new Action1<Contact>() {
         @Override
         public void call(Contact contact) {
             textView.setText(contact.FirstName);
         }
    });
```

any help please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using:

`@GET("/Contact/{Id}")
public Observable(@Path("Id")String Id)`

Instead of:

`@GET("/Contact/{Id}")
public Observable(@Query("Id")String Id);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have got the solution there was no problem in the observable there was in the json parsing.